# Скрытие блока DIV

Tags: html, javascript

Видимо я остаточно поехал, может кто пояснить почему [такой вот](http://jsfiddle.net/27dXq/1/) код не работает?
Задача проста, скрыть блок div..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да вроде всё работает...
http://jsfiddle.net/27dXq/4/

Comment: а ваш первый вариант скорее всего не работал из-за того, что событие window.onload происходило позже, чем кнопке назначался ещё не определённый обработчик

Comment: Нееееее, не то. Код, что выше отличается от вашего только кавычками. Js-вещь точная, он не может выдавать один результат сейчас сейчас, а другой потом. Все дело было в кавычках, getelementbyid принимает string.

Comment: смотрите внимательнее. Вот ваш вариант: http://fiddle.jshell.net/27dXq/1/show/ Откройте код и посмотрите на onload.

Теперь посмотрите на этот вариант: http://fiddle.jshell.net/27dXq/4/show/ - функция объявляется, не ожидая загрузки всего документа, и на момент использования она уже определена.

а кавычки... ну да, это ещё одна ошибка, но она уже более очевидна.

Comment: На самом деле в jsfiddle из-за **window.onload** функция была объявлена не в глобальном контексте,  + кавычки тоже нужны были, только не потому-что getElementById не может сделать *toString*, а потому-что число слишком большое. (**76561198100699401*1 = 76561198100699410**). http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/27dXq/5/

Comment: @jackrv - все ваши беды от того что вы назначаете обработчики в разметке.

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/27dXq/3/

id передается в кавычках, ну и к тому же у вас обработчик события никак не был привязан к html, нужно либо вставить функцию hideBlock в html, а если она в отдельном файле, то импортировать

```
<script src="путь_к_скрипту"></script>
```

Comment: Что значит "никак не привязан"? Я ж писал это специально для этого сервиса, зачем там разделение кода javascript, html тогда?